# WPF double animation | how to specify origin

Tags: wpf, animation

How to specify origin for storyboard based double animation.

Following is the code

```
<Storyboard x:Key="gridin">
  <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:05"  Storyboard.TargetName="gridA" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="100" To="300" ></DoubleAnimation>
  <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:05"  Storyboard.TargetName="gridA" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="100" To="300" ></DoubleAnimation>
 </Storyboard>
```

gridA is a grid on which animation is to be done.

This issue is that gridA animation is started from top middle. 
I want to set origin to 0.5, 0.5 but not able to get where to set this value.

One option is to use somehow RenderTransform and set RenderTransformOrigin. I want to avoid this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place gridA in another (larger) Grid with `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` set to `Center`:

```
<Grid Width="300" Height="300">
    <Grid Name="gridA" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Personally i would prefer to animate a `ScaleTransform` in `RenderTransform`.